# How to plot a phase portrait of Verhulst equation with SciPy (or SymPy) and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, ode, differential-equations

The equation which describes competing species is given by

```
dx/dt = beta\*x - delta\*x\**2 - gamma\*x\*y
dy/dt = b\*y - d\*y\**2 - c\*x\*y
```

I attempted to express this equation as follows:

```py
beta, delta, gamma = 1., 0.1, 0.5
b, d, c = 1.5, 0.5, 0.5

C1 = gamma*c-delta*d
C2 = gamma*b-beta*d
C3 = beta*c-delta*b

def verhulst(X, t=0):
    return np.array([beta*X[0] - delta*X[0]**2 -gamma*X[0]*X[1],
                     b*X[1] - d*X[1]**2 -c*X[0]*X[1]])

X_O = np.array([0., 0.])
X_R = np.array([C2/C1, C3/C1])
X_P = np.array([0, b/d])
X_Q = np.array([beta/delta, 0])

def jacobian(X, t=0):
    return np.array([[beta-delta*2*X[0]-gamma*X[1],  -gamma*x[0]],
                     [b-d*2*X[1]-c*X[0],             -c*X[1]]])

values  = np.linspace(0.3, 0.9, 5)                         
vcolors = plt.cm.autumn_r(np.linspace(0.3, 1., len(values)))

f2 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))

for v, col in zip(values, vcolors):
    X0 = v * X_R
    X = odeint(verhulst, X0, t)
    plt.plot(X[:,0], X[:,1], color=col, label='X0=(%.f, %.f)' % ( X0[0], X0[1]) )

ymax = plt.ylim(ymin=0)[1] 
xmax = plt.xlim(xmin=0)[1]
nb_points = 20

x = np.linspace(0, xmax, nb_points)
y = np.linspace(0, ymax, nb_points)

X1, Y1  = np.meshgrid(x, y)
DX1, DY1 = verhulst([X1, Y1])  # compute growth rate on the gridt
M = (np.hypot(DX1, DY1))       # Norm of the growth rate
M[M == 0] = 1.                 # Avoid zero division errors
DX1 /= M                       # Normalize each arrows
DY1 /= M

plt.quiver(X1, Y1, DX1, DY1, M, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.xlabel('Number of Species 1')
plt.ylabel('Number of Species 2')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
```

The plot I get is

[image]

But what I'd like to obtain is

[image]

I guess there is something wrong with the codes, so where is the error？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing the coordinates of the second graphic, you want `R=[1/3, 1/3]`, `P=[0, 1/2]` and `Q=[1/2,0]` which can be realized with

```
beta, delta, gamma = 1, 2, 1
b,d,c = 1,2,1
```

With that and some different initial points I get the plot

[image]

which looks closer to the desired plot.

Comment: Yes, thank you. In fact, I neglected that this equation should be discussed in two cases if I would like to get `X_R = np.array([C2/C1, C3/C1])` in 1st quadrant. One is the situation you mentioned (C1, C2, C3>0). So I have another question: since this equation describes the growth of populations, how am I supposed to understand the situation of coexistence when `birth rate` < `death rate`?